# AVD Emulator is terminated while launching in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

After installing Android Studio, the AVD emulator is not working. It shows below error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KKM.png)

Android Studio - version - Flamingo | 2022.2.1